# How to get the Excel-File id using the filename in microsoft-graph api?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the File Id using the filename in graph API
I have tried the following thing but this is not working

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/ccc.sharepoint.com,dddddd,eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/drive/root:/excelDir/filename.xlsx:/children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+webAndSiteId+"/drives/"+folderID+"/root/search(q='filename.xlsx')
```

Below is the working javascript

```
var fileCollectionEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+webAndSiteId+"/drives/"+folderID+"/root/search(q='"+fileNamesArray[index]+"')"


$.ajax({
    url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    cache:false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,
    },
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json.value[0].id);

    },
    error:function(xhr)
    {

    }
});
```